# How to assign numerous objects with identical properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

How do you create numerous objects under the same method with identical properties in Javascript?

Im familiar with how to create objects in Javascript as such:

```
var myCar = new Object(); 
myCar.make = 'ford';
myCar.model = 'mustang';
myCar.year = 1969;
```

But what if I wanted to assign an array to an object and have all the values have the same properties?

```
Arr = [1,2];
Arr[i].value === Arr[i]
Arr[j].value === Arr[j]
Arr[i].value === Arr[j].value
!Arr[i].hasOwnProperty('value')
!Arr[j].hasOwnProperty('value')
```

where as the value method is the same and not unique to the object

```
object1.hasOwnProperty('value'); //Evaluates to `false`
```

I'm used to programming in Python so my first guess is to create a dictionary and dynamically assign the array to the `values` but I'm not sure how to work with `properties` in Javascript objects.

Edit: Mistakenly included '==' operators when I meant to use '===' operators.

Comment: Well your `==` there is an evaluation, not an assignment. But why would you like to set a property `value` on a number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this - by creating an object. Also use the assignment operator `=` not comparison operator `==`:

```js
let Arr = [1,2];
let i = 0;
let j = 1;
Arr[i] = { value: Arr[i] };
Arr[j] = { value: Arr[j] };
console.log(Arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I meant to use '===' operator not '=='

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're asking for but you can create your own objects in two ways

```
function Car (make, model, year) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

// you can also add methods using the object's protoype
Car.prototype.isNissan() {
    return this.make == 'Nissan';
}
```

In modern syntax you can create classes

```
class Car {
    constructor(make, model, year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

    methodName() {
        // method body
    }
}
```

And use it in your code like so

```
let myCar = new Car('Nissan', 'some model', 2018);
```